# How to add a button to a DataGrid while at the same time autogenerating its values? (C#, WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

So I have a method that accepts a DataTable and puts into the DataGrid like so:

```
myDataGrid.DataContext = myDataTable;
myDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

I've tried adding in an ItemSource like so:

```
ObservableCollection<Button> buttons = new ObservableCollection<Button>();
buttons.Add(new Button() { Content = "Open" });
dg.ItemsSource = buttons;
```

But it just messes up the entire thing, replacing the columns with `Button` property names and the rows with `myButton` values.

**tl;dr:** Is there anyway to add a button to each row without messing up the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add a button, or any other control, to the cell of a data grid by binding against a list of buttons. You should be using the ItemsSource for binding against the actual data you want displayed in the rows.

Instead you need to add a [DataGridTemplateColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) instance to your data grids column collection. Then assign a template to the column that specifies a Button for display in each row of that new column.